# Matching spacing around electric pairs

Tags: electric-pair-mode

In `c-mode`, `rust-mode`, and similar major language modes, I frequently type something such as the following Rust:

```
if some_bool { Some(foo) } else { None }
```

As I enter this (`|` represents my cursor), electric-pair mode inserts matching brackets:

```
if some_bool { |}
```

Is there a setting that allows Emacs to insert matching space on the other side of the cursor following an opening character of a pair, so the above example would look like the following?

```
if some_bool { | }
```

I would expect it to behave exactly like additional parens had been inserted, and backspacing at this point should produce

```
if some_bool {|}
```

again.

Answer (score 1):

With [`smartparens`](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens), you can add a `:post-handler`, like this:

```
(sp-pair "{" nil :post-handlers '(("| " "SPC")))
```

I use an additional handler for pressing return:

```
(sp-pair "{" nil :post-handlers '(("||\n[i]" "RET")
                                  ("| " "SPC")))
```

Comment: This almost works, but it doesn't handle pressing backspace.  (Although it does still delete the matching close brace when I delete the opening one.  Is there an extra rule I can use to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [electric-spacing](https://github.com/xwl/electric-spacing) or [electric-operator](https://github.com/davidshepherd7/electric-operator). You might need to configure it a bit for your use case, but it aims to automatically pad certain characters with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `electric-pair-mode` will be of much help to you here.  You *could* add `(?\s . ?\s)` to `electric-pair-pairs` (its alist of characters to automatically double-insert), but that would affect every space you type (there is no way to add conditions as to when it will/won't insert a pair) and will probably play havoc with skipping over whitespace.  Also, w.r.t. automatically deleting a matching space, `electric-pair-mode` doesn't do anything magical.  It simply scans its list of characters to insert as pairs and removes the next character if it finds a match with the one you've deleted.  Again, adding `(?\s . ?\s)` to `electric-pair-pairs` would be a poor solution.

So, I solved this by adding my own functions for the purpose...

```el
(defun my/c-mode-insert-space (arg)
  (interactive "*P")
  (let ((prev (char-before))
        (next (char-after)))
    (self-insert-command (prefix-numeric-value arg))
    (if (and prev next
             (string-match-p "[[({]" (string prev))
             (string-match-p "[])}]" (string next)))
        (save-excursion (self-insert-command 1)))))

(defun my/c-mode-delete-space (arg &optional killp)
  (interactive "*p\nP")
  (let ((prev (char-before))
        (next (char-after))
        (pprev (char-before (- (point) 1))))
    (if (and prev next pprev
             (char-equal prev ?\s) (char-equal next ?\s)
             (string-match "[[({]" (string pprev)))
        (delete-char 1))
    (backward-delete-char-untabify arg killp)))
```

You can bind them in c-mode (and its derivatives) like this:

```el
(add-hook 'c-mode-common-hook
          (lambda ()
            (local-set-key " " 'my/c-mode-insert-space)
            (local-set-key "\177" 'my/c-mode-delete-space)))
```